# SSRS Export to Excel has Wrong Group Footers

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services report that has several layers of groups. The groups have footers but no headers. Each sub-group's visibility is initially hidden and can be toggled from a cell in the footer of its parent group.

The report renders fine in the browser. However, when I export to Excel the groupings are wrong. With three layers of groups the last item in the second layer is not collapsable in Excel. The last item in the third layer is collapsable but not initially collapsed like it should be and is in the browser.

Is there anything I can do differently to make this work?

Comment: Have you found a reason or solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a high enough rep to add comments so I am posting my comment here.

Do you summation expressions in those lines like this.

```
=sum(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

I have noticed with excel that it has no way to conditionally represent a summation like the one above when you collapse a group.

This means that the information has to go somewhere, as excel will not truncate information, and is represented by the addition of a line with the summation the same as the =sum() expression in excel.